# WPF Development for Windows 8 Pro Tablet

Tags: windows-8, tablet, on-screen-keyboard

I'm trying to design a WPF desktop application for a Windows 8 Pro tablet device. I don't want a windows store application because of the limitations within RT.

So, I'm really having trouble using the built in touch screen keyboard. Do anybody know of any online tutorials for Windows 8 development using WPF and tablets.

If not, is using Apple/Android a better option?

Thanks

Comment: What type of problems are you having with the keyboard ?

Comment: Hi Mark, basically I can get the keyboard to show by using this line of code: Process p = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe"); But when I want to close the keyboard using p.Close() or p.Kill(). I get an error saying that the Process has exited. But yet the keyboard is still on the screen. I'd also like to position the keyboard and set it to it's maximized state. If you can help with this that would be amazing!